# Error with "String Index out of Range" within another method?

Tags: java

I'm having a problem trying to reverse a string, in which it says that I'm having a "String index out of range" error. Thanks for any help, i'll leave the code and error below.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Text Converter.");
        System.out.println("Available Actions:");
        System.out.println("\t1337) convert to 1337 speak");
        System.out.println("\trev) reverse the string");
        System.out.println("\tquit) exit the program");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Please enter a string: ");
        String userString;
        String action;
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        userString = scnr.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Action (1337, rev, quit): ");
        action = scnr.nextLine();   
        while (!action.equals("quit")) {
            if (action.equals("rev")) {
                actionReverse(userString);

            }
            if(action.equals("1337")) {
                action1337(userString);
            }
        }
```

```
    public static String actionReverse(String userString) {
            String newString = "";
            for(int i=userString.length(); i>=0; --i) {
                newString = newString + userString.charAt(i);

            }


            return newString;  
        }
```

Error Message:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
    String index out of range: 3
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at TextConverter.actionReverse(TextConverter.java:82)
    at TextConverter.main(TextConverter.java:19)

Answer (score 0):

As it says the index is out of range, you need to write 
`for(int i=userString.length() - 1; i>=0; --i)` because strings are zero-indexed.

While I'm passing, I want to mention that this string concatenation is considered quite slow and if performance is important you should use a `StringBuilder` for string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

The source of your issue is an off-by-one error. The indices of `String` start at 0 and end at `str.length() - 1`.

So your `for` loop should look something like this:

```
for(int i = userString.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    newString += userString.charAt(i);
}
```

However, a more efficient method of reversing the `String` would be to use a `StringBuilder`. Since `StringBuilder` is mutable, it is much better performance-wise to use that instead of appending to a `String` directly.

```
public static String actionReverse(String userString) {
    return new StringBuilder(userString).reverse().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems the index of last item is incorrect.
change it to `userString.length() - 1`

```
for (int i = userString.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            newString = newString + userString.charAt(i);
}
```